# Is there a way to programatically style radio button

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating RadioButtons programatically and I would like to apply marginStart add blue buttonTint color and change the font size of the text next to it:

```
data.forEach { d ->
                val radioButton = RadioButton(getApplicationContext())
                radioButton.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                )
                radioButton.text = d.text
                rgButtons.addView(radioButton)
            }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe use ContextThemeWrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.....

```
val radioButton = RadioButton(getApplicationContext())
val layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
 //For margin use this line 

 // layoutParams.setMargins(10,0,0,0); //you can try this and check
    layoutParams.marginStart=10
  
//for backgroudTintColor
    radioButton.backgroundTintList= ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.red) ))
    radioButton.layoutParams=layoutParams
   
    radioButton.textSize = 30F //for text Size

    radioButton.text = d.text
    rgButtons.addView(radioButton)
```

if not work then let me know.

Comment: Nice, thank you! Is it possible to change the colour of the radio button when it's not checked to grey?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way you can customize a radio button. What you can do is make a custom view `(a empty outlined circle)` and another view for `Filled-in circle` inside it. Now you need to write the functionality so that it behaves like a radio button. This is the only way you can achieve a custom radio button.